# I want to ask about life span of lion

Tags: sentence-structure

Which one is correct?
How long life span lions have?
Or
How long do lions have life span?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, neither of your options are grammatically correct.

Your best bet would be something along the lines of:

> What is the life span of the average lion?

You might want to add in gender, as, with many species, it's possible that the males and females do not live as long as each other:

> What is the life span of the average male/female lion?

You could also say one of the following:

> On average, how long do lions live?
>
> Typically, how old are lions when they die?

Answer (score 4):

You have a number of options:

1. What is the average lifespan of lions?
2. How long on average do lions live?
3. What is the average life expectancy of lions?

I am sure there are many ways to rephrase this.

Answer (score 2):

You've already received some answers with good alternative phrasings.

I would ask

> How long do lions live?

Which is fairly close to your example "How long do lions have life span?"

To give you a grammatical sentence as close to "How long life span lions have?" your example sentences as possible:

> How long is the life span of lions?

or

> How long is the life span that lions have?

Comment: I would think that plural lions would have plural life spans as well. Each of us only gets one.